# How to approve Azure OMS agents successfully installed to Windows VMs

Tags: azure, oms

Just installed a few Azure OMS agents to some non-critical Windows Server VMs.  At the end of the install, it says this:

"Additionally, you must approve the agent in the Pending Managment view in the Administration section of the console..."

Anybody know where this is located?  Microsoft is in the middle of moving the separate OMS portal into the main Azure portal, so I am not sure which of those to look in.  Haven't found it yet and I will keep looking.

[image: Microsoft Monotoring Agent Completion Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Additionally, you must approve the agent in the Pending Managment
>   view in the Administration section of the console..."

You can ignore it if this installation of the agent is not connected to System Center Operations Manager. If you have System Center Operations Manager connected. You can view it via the following path:

Open your SCOM environment and navigate to Administration > Pending Management, Get more details from [this](http://scug.be/dieter/2015/05/08/microsoft-operations-management-suite-connect-datasources/).

In this case, you just click **Finish** to complete the installation. Back in the OMS Dashboard, You can see a data source has been connected.

[image]

When **complete**, the Microsoft Monitoring Agent appears in **Control Panel**. To confirm it is reporting to Log Analytics, review [Verify agent connectivity to Log Analytics.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-agent-windows#verify-agent-connectivity-to-log-analytics)

[image]

Comment: Update, please let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: Excellent, you are 100% correct.  I am not using System Center Operations Manager, and my agents are fully connected already.  So I am good to go!  Thank you.

Comment: Also, bear in mind you don't need to install the OMS agent manually using the installer. You can use the VM extension to install it for you at deploy time.